# dynamic animation of ng-include not firing done callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I need to transition between different ng-include templates using dynamic transitions.
For example in transitioning from A to B:

> Page A enters from the left -> Leaves through the right
>    Page B enters from the bottom -> Leaves through the top

I've done it and it looks nice.  HOWEVER - it seems like the done callback in the animation module is never being called and as a result, the dynamically included templates are never removed... so I get node-elements accumulating off screen.

My HTML tag that is being animated has these set:

> ng-include="pageData.template"
>    class='{{pageData.animation}}'

and an animation module which looks like this:

```
(function() {

angular.module('xxxxxxxx')
.animation('.slide-up', [slideUp])
.animation('.slide-down', [slideDown])
.animation('.slide-right', [slideRight])
.animation('.slide-left', [slideLeft]);

var bottom =    { top:"100%", };

var mid =       { top:"0",  left:"0", };

var top =       { top:"-100%", };

var left =      { left:"-100%", };

var right =     { left:"100%", };

function slideUp(){
    return {
        enter: function(element, done){
            console.log('entering animation: slideup');
            element.css('position','absolute');
            element.css(bottom);
            Velocity(element, mid, 
                            {   duration : xxxxxxxx.animation.duration,
                                end: done, 
                            });
        },

        leave: function(element, done){
            console.log('leaving animation slideup');
            element.css('position','absolute');
            element.css(mid);
            Velocity(element, top, 
                            {
                                duration : xxxxxxxx.animation.duration,
                                end: done,
                            }
                );
        },


};
}

function slideRight(){
    return {
        enter: function(element, done){
            console.log('entering animation slideRight');
            element.css('position','absolute');
            element.css(left);
            Velocity(element, mid, 
                            {
                                duration : xxxxxxxx.animation.duration,
                                end: done,
                            }
                );
        },
        leave: function(element, done){
            console.log('leaving animation slideRight');
            element.css('position','absolute');
            element.css(mid);
            Velocity(element, right, 
                            {
                                duration : xxxxxxxx.animation.duration,
                                end: done,
                            }
                );
    },
};
}
... continued
```

The transitions are triggered by setting the $scope.pageData.animation and $scope.pageData.template variables.

I'm interested in both a wiser way of accomplishing this same goal... for the future.  As well as any hackish ideas to move forward with this implementation.

thanks

Comment: I think you should try https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. it is really simple to implement then angular animation